# std::this_thread::sleep_for() and GCC

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++11, g++

When I try to compile this simple program:

```
#include<thread>

void f() {
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
}

int main() {
  std::thread t(f);
  t.join();
}
```

with gcc version 4.4.3 on Ubuntu 10.04 (32 bit):

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -pthread a.cpp -o a
```

I get:

```
error: ‘sleep_for’ is not a member of ‘std::this_thread’
```

I looked in header 'thread'.
sleep_for() is protected with _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP

```
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP
...
/// sleep_for
template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
  inline void
  sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
...
```

Why is `_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP` not defined?
How do I get this example to compile?

---

**Update 17 Sep 2012** (jogojapan): I ran into this same problem today, using GCC 4.7.1. I wonder if there is any news on how to avoid it, other than by defining `_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP`. I tried using `-std=gnu11`, but to no avail.

There is also an old, unresolved bug report for GCC 4.4: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.4/+bug/608145

---

**Update 19 Oct 2012** (jogojapan): The issue has now been explained and resolved by Jonathan Wakely as an anwer to this question: [What is _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523122/what-is-glibcxx-use-nanosleep-all-about)
This is particularly relevant for anyone who builds GCC himself instead of using a ready-made package.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Confirmed that it doesn't work here as well. (Recent GCC 4.6 snapshot).

You could do the obvious and simply define it before you include any std:: headers. A bit dirty but will work until GCC fixes it (unless this is intended behavior). The #define shouldn't break anything anyways. Either in source or -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP flag to GCC.

You might want to try using -std=gnu++0x rather than -std=c++0x, since gnu++0x often pulls in stuff like this.

Answer (score 7):

Additional information, in case it helps someone:

I do not need to define `_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP` in Ubuntu 11.10, gcc 4.6.1, glibc 2.13.

But I *do* need to compile with -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP on Gentoo, gcc 4.6.1, glibc 2.12.2.

I am not going to compile the Gentoo system for updating the glibc. At least not before the weekend ;)

Comment: same problem on mac osx mac ports gcc 4.7.2 with the  `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP` fix solving it

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work without the define on ubuntu 13.04 using gcc version 4.7.3

Answer (score 1):

Need to define `_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP` on top of the source code.

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP  //add it top of c++ code
```

OR, Compile with following commamd:

```
g++ a.cpp -o a -std=c++0x -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP    //compile c++ code
./a       // run c++ code
```

Comment: not work on macOS