# Handling mutual exclusion in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutual-exclusion

I have a class representing a finite-state machine, which should run in a forever loop and check it's current state. In each state machine will set it's next state and either fall into `idle` state or do some work. I would like to allow another thread to change state of machine while it's working. This will cause a race condition as expected. So I add a mutual exclusion lock/unlock wrapping loop of machine and the public method that allows other threads to change current state of machine.

```
class Robot
{
public:
    enum StateType {s1,s2,s3,idle,finish};
    void run();
    void move();
private:
    StateType currentState;
    StateType nextState;
    StateType previousState;
    std::mutex mutal_state;
};
```

Implementation:

```
void Robot::run()
{
    this->currentState = s1;
    while(true)
    {
        mutal_state.lock();
        switch(currentState)
        {
        case s1:
            // do some useful stuff here...
            currentState = idle;
            nextState = s3;
            break;
        case s2:
            // do some other useful stuff here...
            currentState = idle;
            nextState = finish;
            break;
        case s3:
            // again, do some useful things...
            currentState = idle;
            nextState = s2;
            break;
        case idle:
            // busy waiting...
            std::cout << "I'm waiting" << std::endl;
            break;
        case finish:
            std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
            mutal_state.unlock();
            return;
        }
        mutal_state.unlock();
    }
}
```

And the move method that allows other threads to change current state:

```
void Robot::move()
{
    mutal_state.lock();
    previousState = currentState; // Booommm
    currentState = nextState;
    mutal_state.unlock();
}
```

I can't manage to find what I'm doing wrong! Program crashes in first line of the `move()` function. On the other hand, the GDB is not working with C++11 and tracing code is not possible...

**UPDATE:**

Playing around code, I can see that problem is in move function. When the program tries to lock code piece inside `move()`, crashes. For example if move is like this:

```
void Robot::move()
{
    std::cout << "MOVE IS CALLED" << std::endl;
    mutal_state.lock();
    //previousState = currentState;
    //std::cout << "MOVING" << std::endl;
    //currentState = nextState;
    mutal_state.unlock();
}
```

Output is:

```
s1
I'm waiting
I'm waiting
MOVE IS CALLED1
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

But when `move` is a simple function, not doing anything:

```
void Robot::move()
{
    std::cout << "MOVE IS CALLED" << std::endl;
    //mutal_state.lock();
    //previousState = currentState;
    //std::cout << "MOVING" << std::endl;
    //currentState = nextState;
    //mutal_state.unlock();
}
```

Program runs concurrently.

Comment: Well have you tried debugging with print statements?

Comment: @ FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Yes. I know that the "explosion" only happens when some thread tries to call ``move``.

Comment: What version of what compiler are you using?

Comment: @ildjarn: I'm using gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) and thread model is posix

Comment: How is `previousState` declared?

Comment: @Tudor: It's a private member of class. Just forgot to write it in question :-)

Comment: Is an exception being thrown?  I so, can you catch it?  Presumably, currentState or 'this' are not correctly accessible.  Are you sure that the the other threads all have access to the same instance?

Comment: You'd do well to start using lock guards (e.g. `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`, `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`) rather than manually locking and unlocking. This may not help with your immediate issue but can only help for maintenance/static verification. Not to mention exception safety.

Comment: Are you sure the crash occurs exactly at that line? Is it a segfault? Maybe the crash occurs when the thread executes some branch of the switch. Did you try to see in which state the thread goes and which code is executed?

Comment: @Tudor: Yes, I'm sure. I tried printing some outputs in `move` before and after calling `mutal_state.lock()`. only first one is printed and it's the last thing program says.

Comment: I am in the odd state of being grateful my answer was helpful and accepted, but unsure of which suggestion was the one that worked.  Any chance of some detail on what fixed the issue?

Comment: @MattT: First one! I traced code by hand and found that it's completely different issue. Ownership of an object is changed after spawning a thread on a member function of it. See my answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestions:

1) if you have no debugger, how can you be so sure it is the first line of move that crashes?  It is always with questioning any assumptions you have made about the code, unless you have hard evidence to back it up.

2) I would look at whatever interesting code is in state s3, as this is what the first call to move will perform.  Up to that point the code in s3 has not been run.  Either that or remove all code bar what is in the posted example, to rule this out.

3) The compiler may make copies of the variables in registers, you should declare all the states as volatile so it knows not to optimise in this way.

Answer (score 2):

I can not help you why your code "explodes", however I can assume that the problem is not in the code you posted as it runs fine for me.

This will output for me:

```
I'm working
...
Bye
```

Code:

```
int main() {

    Robot r;

    auto async_moves = [&] () {  // simulate some delayed interaction
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2)); //See note
        for(auto i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
            r.move();

    };

    auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async, async_moves);

    r.run();

}
```

(Note: You have to compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP` assuming you are using gcc, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438084/893693) question.)

Note that the code above - and yours maybe, too - is still vulnurable to the problem, that the states may get invalidated if `move` is called twice or more before the loop triggers again.
Like one of the comments already mentioned, prefer to use lock_guards:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutal_state);
```

Comment: Trying `std::lock_guard` didn't help. However I can't run your code. It terminates: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted'`

Comment: @sorush-r You have to add the -pthread compiler option. That will fix that error.

Comment: @sorush-r doesn't make sense to me as that is exactly the error I get without `-pthread`, I am compiling like this `g++ -std=c++0x -pthread -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP -o main main.cpp`

Comment: Oops! sorry, I'm using Qt build system, and forgot to do a `qmake` after adding `-lpthread` to .pro file. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using g++ on linux, you need to link with -lpthread in order for mutexes or threading stuff to work properly.  If you don't, it won't fail to link, but will instead behave badly or crash at runtime...

Comment: It is probably better to use the -pthread option. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2127797/893693. However, I assume he did that anyway.

Comment: I'm using both `-pthread` and `-lpthread` linker options. There is no problem with linking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question! Because I find the problem, and It was not related to locking nor mutex implementation of C++0x. There is an `ImageProcess` class that should control state of `Robot`. It has a pointer to it's parent of type `Robot*` and using that, will `move` its parent.  For that I've implemented a `workhorse` and a `start`er function. The `start` spawns a `std::tread` and runs `workhorse` on it:

```
void ImageProcess::start()
{
    std::thread x(&ImageProcess::workhorse, *this);
    x.detach();
}
```

I realized that `this->parent` in workhorse is a dangling pointer. Obviously calling `parent->move()` should crash. But it don't crash immediately! Surprisingly program control enters into `move()` function and then tries to change `previousState` of a non-existing `Robot` thing. (or lock a mutex of non-existing `Robot`).

I found that when invoking a thread like `std::thread x(&ImageProcess::workhorse, *this); x.join() or x.detach()`, the code is no longer running in caller object. To test I printed address of `this` and `&image` in both `Robot::run()` and `ImageProcess::workhorse`. There were different. I also added a public boolean `foo` to `ImageProcess` and changed its value to `true` in `Robot`, then printed it in `workhorse` and `run`, in `workhorse` value is always `0` but in `Robot` is `1`.

I believe this is very strange behavior. I don't know if it's related to memory model or ownership of `ImageProcess` somehow is changed after `std::thread x(&ImageProcess::workhorse, *this)`...

I make `ImageProcess` a factory pattern class (everything is static!). Now it's OK.