# error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, mingw, glibc

I try to use std::this_thread::sleep_for() function but got the error
`error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared`.
The flag _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP included.
What else is needed to force it to work?
MinGW ==> gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC)

SSCCE:

```
#include<thread>

int main() {
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
}
```

command line:

```
g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP -std=gnu++0x ssce.cpp -o ssce.exe
```

result of compilation:

```
ssce.cpp: In function 'int main()':
ssce.cpp:4:8: error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared
```

Comment: Have you `#include <thread>`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438084/stdthis-threadsleep-for-and-gcc?

Comment: sorry, yes, I use that include

Comment: Please present a real testcase, so your ten-line example C++ program and your build command.

Comment: Just a moment. I'll prepare the example.

Comment: Do you build with the `-std=c++11` flag?

Comment: MinGw doesn't support threading features out of the box.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I use -std=gnu++0x

Comment: @bamboon: so, no way to use sleep_for()?

Comment: @OlegG there probably is a way to make that work, just search around a bit and you will probably find quite a lot on this topic.

Comment: Can you please make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: yes, see, pls, initial question text

Comment: Is boost::threads an option for you? The functionality should be similar enough. Otherwise you could write `sleep_for` on basis of e.g. pthreads. If you are interested I think I might still have the source for the later lying around somewhere from when I ran into the same problem.

Comment: @Grizzly: Actually I've overcome this using boost. Right like you said. But I want to use std everywhere it is possible. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use MinGW with POSIX threads, Luke.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/

Comment: thank you! The compiler being MinGW made the difference.

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all. The asker is *already* using MinGW. It's MinGW that is causing this problem in the first place. Also, that is not the link to MinGW. It should be: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/.

Comment: mingw w64 apparently has two modes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358856/does-mingw-w64-support-stdthread-out-of-the-box-when-using-the-win32-threading