# std::this_thread::sleep_for doesn't exist - Windows 10 g++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am currently running a test program which executes perfectly well online (replit.com), but when I run it locally (on Windows 10 with gcc and g++) I get an error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:18:8: error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(time));
```

This is my program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <string>

int randomInt (int MIN, int MAX) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(MIN, MAX);
    return distr(eng);
}

int main() {
    int loop = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        int time = randomInt(10, 100);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(time));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: What is the version of g++ and how you invoke it?

Comment: You need to pass `-std=c++11` (or newer) as a command line parameter to g++.  Many versions of g++ default to an older version the language standard.  Without passing that parameter, you should gotten even more errors than just the one about `this_thread`

Comment: @selbie I run this command: `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test` and it still doesn't work

Comment: @S.M. I am using g++ 6.3. Command: `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test`

Comment: Can not [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/Mef5Yjbsf).

Comment: @康桓瑋 could you try this on a windows system?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741711/error-stdthis-thread-has-not-been-declared

https://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/267237/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went back to replit.com to see what they were doing to compile the program. Apparently they used the `-pthreads` switch:

```
g++ -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
```

Which now works for me.