# How to let this_thread::sleep_for(a while)?

Tags: c++, c++11, sleep, stdthread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::this_thread::sleep_for() and GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438084/stdthis-threadsleep-for-and-gcc)

Tried to write a simple timer and some code to test it by letting the program sleep for some time:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

Aux::Timer timer;
timer.start();
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
timer.stop();
std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::milli> t = timer.elapsed();
```

This gives me a compiler error:

```
17:45:28 **** Incremental Build of configuration EnsembleClustering-DPar for project EnsembleClustering ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/aux/test/AuxGTest.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
/usr/local/bin/g++-4.7 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7.2/gcc/include/c++/4.7.2 -I/Users/cls/workspace/gtest/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/log4cxx/0.10.0/include -I/Users/cls/workspace/STINGER/include -O0 -g3 -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -p -pg -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -g -pg -fopenmp -MMD -MP -MF"src/aux/test/AuxGTest.d" -MT"src/aux/test/AuxGTest.d" -o "src/aux/test/AuxGTest.o" "../src/aux/test/AuxGTest.cpp"
../src/aux/test/AuxGTest.cpp: In member function 'virtual void AuxGTest_testTimer_Test::TestBody()':
../src/aux/test/AuxGTest.cpp:72:2: error: 'sleep_for' is not a member of 'std::this_thread'
make: *** [src/aux/test/AuxGTest.o] Error 1
```

I haven't used the `<thread>` library before. Can you suggest a quick fix? I'd also be happy with an alternative for testing the correctness of the timer.

Comment: That looks suspiciously correct. Does your standard library implementation actually have `sleep_for`? It appears that's what the error is.

Comment: Here you go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438084/stdthis-threadsleep-for-and-gcc

Comment: @Dave it does, and it's conditional on `_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP`.

Comment: Fixed it with a `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP 1` at the beginning of the file, as described in the answer linked by @Ajay

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12961816/981959 for a proper explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue described here: [std::this_thread::sleep_for() and GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438084/stdthis-threadsleep-for-and-gcc)

with a `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP 1` at the beginning of the file.